# managing delegates - secondary calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange, calendar, outlook-web-access

In Outlook 2010 I had access to two calendars from my boss: the "primary" one and a secondary one (but now I don't remember how I added the latter). 
By error I deleted the secondary calendar (instead of hiding). Now I don't know how to add it again.

I found some instructions ( http://forums.bit-tech.net/showthread.php?p=2765788, 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/98221c5f-d165-4fe5-bca7-bf3e67b17ea4/shared-secondary-outlook-calendar?forum=outlook), but I think they don't apply to my case since I still should have the permissions on this secondary calendar. I already tried to open my boss calendar, but only the primary one pops out (both in outlook 2010 and owa).

Is there a way to see all the elements I have already been given permission? Or some other way to recover this calendar?

Answer (score 0):

I found the first original invitation mail with an "open this calendar" button, and I could successfully open the calendar again.